# how do i set the size of my window gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, size, gridbaglayout

I'm using gridbaglayout and I want my window to be 700 x 500 always.  I also was my JButtons to be the exact same size but if the word inside them is longer they get longer and I can't have this.  How can I do this?  Please help me with good code I been trying for hours.

I tried to do frame.setSize and panel.setSize but neither work and I need this fast!  Please help!

Answer (score 4):

The basic answer is, you don't.  That's not the point of any layout manager.

A layout manager simple makes decisions about how best to layout it's children based on the sizing hints that they provide.

Remember, while it might look great on your screen, the next computer you run it on may make it look like crap.

If you "must" define the size of anything, then you need to override the `getPreferredSize` method of your component and return an appropriate size hint.

Having said that, I wouldn't do this for components like `JButton` (or actually anything other than `JPanel` and `JComponent`), the way they calculate their sizes are complicated and best left alone.

You can modify the size of components through the use of `Border`s and, in the case of `GridBagLayout`, `Insets` and modifying the `GridBagConstraints` properties.

Have a closer look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for some more ideas